# syntax error near unexpected token '&' When I use powershell in gitlab

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
    GIT_PATH: 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe'
stages:
    - build
build_job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - ' & $env:GIT_PATH ./all_build.bat'
```

sometime it can run, but sometimes it can't run. why?
error:

```
/bin/bash: eval: line 82: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

Comment: I guess that you need to (double) quote `$env:GIT_PATH` in case it contains a space: `' & "$env:GIT_PATH" ./all_build.bat'`

Comment: thx your reply. finally: - ./all_build.bat